# Using expressions in the "Select" part of LINQ to entities queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd like to be able to reuse the "select" portions of my LINQ to Entities queries. For example, I can take the following...

```
projectQuery.Select(p => new ProjectModel
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
    ProjectNumber = p.ProjectNumber);
```

and replace it with an expression...

```
projectQuery.Select(ProjectModel.FullSelector);
```

where FullSelector looks like this:

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Project, ProjectModel>> FullSelector = project => new ProjectModel
{
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
    ProjectNumber = p.ProjectNumber
};
```

This works great, and the query sent to the database only selects the fields that are used by the FullSelector. Plus I can reuse the FullSelector every time I need to query for Project entities.

Now for the tricky part. When doing queries that contain navigational properties, the nested selector expressions do not work.

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Project, ProjectModel>> FullSelector = project => new ProjectModel
{
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
    ProjectNumber = p.ProjectNumber
    Addresses = p.Addresses.Select(AddressModel.FullSelector);
};
```

This does not work. The inner Select gives the compile time error "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

The following example compiles but crashes when the query is executed saying "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.":

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Project, ProjectModel>> FullSelector = project => new ProjectModel
{
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
    ProjectNumber = p.ProjectNumber
    Addresses = p.Addresses.Select(AddressModel.FullSelector.Compile());
};
```

The next example compiles but throws the runtime error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'EPIC.WebAPI.Models.AddressModel Invoke(EPIC.Domain.Entities.Address)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Project, ProjectModel>> FullSelector = project => new ProjectModel
{
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
    ProjectNumber = p.ProjectNumber
    Addresses = p.Addresses.Select(a => AddressModel.PartialSelector.Compile().Invoke(a));
};
```

Does anyone know how to get the inner select to work? I understand why the last example doesn't work, but are the first two close to working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, first off, why doesn't your code work.  The first snippet:

```
p.Addresses.Select(AddressModel.FullSelector);
```

This doesn't work because the navigational properties do not implement `IQueryable`, they implement `ICollection`.  `ICollection` of course doesn't have a `Select` method that accepts an `Expression` parameter.

The second snippet:

```
p.Addresses.Select(AddressModel.FullSelector.Compile());
```

This doesn't work because `FullSelector` is being compiled.  Since it's being compiled, the query provider can't look into the body of the method and translate the code into SQL code.

The third snippet has the exact same problem as the second.  Wrapping it in a lambda doesn't change that fact.

---

So, now that we know why your code doesn't work, what to do now?

This is going to be a bit mind boggling, and I'm not a huge fan of the design of this method, but here we go.  We'll write a method that accepts an expression representing a function with one argument, then it'll accept another that accepts some unrelated type, then *a function of the same type as the delegate in our first parameter*, and then returns an unrelated type.

The implementation of this method can simply replace all instances of the delegate parameter used with the expression that we have, and then wrap it all up in a new lambda:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2>> Use<T1, T2, T3, T4>(
    this Expression<Func<T3, T4>> expression,
    Expression<Func<T1, Func<T3, T4>, T2>> other)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2>>(
        other.Body.Replace(other.Parameters[1], expression),
        other.Parameters[0]);
}
//another overload if there are two selectors
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2>> Use<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(
    this Expression<Func<T3, T4>> firstExpression,
    Expression<Func<T5, T6>> secondExpression,
    Expression<Func<T1, Func<T3, T4>, Func<T5, T6>, T2>> other)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2>>(
        other.Body.Replace(other.Parameters[1], firstExpression)
            .Replace(other.Parameters[2], secondExpression),
        other.Parameters[0]);
}
```

The idea is kinda mind boggling, but the code is actually quite short.  It relies on this method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now to call it we can call `Use` on our address selector and then write a method that accepts both our normal parameter as well as the delegate for the address selector:

```
public static Expression<Func<Project, ProjectModel>> FullSelector =
    AddressModel.FullSelector.Use((Project project,
        Func<Address, AddressModel> selector) => new ProjectModel
        {
            ProjectName = project.ProjectName,
            ProjectNumber = project.ProjectNumber,
            Addresses = project.Addresses.Select(selector),
        });
```

And now this will work exactly as desired.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Thanks. How would this be done if there were multiple navigational properties, for example, if below Addresses there was a property called ProjectManagers?

Comment: @Bumper You'd have to create an additional `Use` method that accepted two selectors and passed both of them to the last one.  I edited such an overload into the question.  I hope you could see the pattern if you need to create one for three, four, etc. selectors.

Comment: Mine got `Replace` method undefined. Where is it?

Comment: @Servy sorry my bad. Guess I need another coffee, too much for today.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I realized that my earlier answer didn't actually answer the question, so I deleted it; I then realized what it was you were asking and realized the easiest way to resolve the issue would most likely be to say in your expression:

```
Addresses = p.Addresses.AsQueryable().Select(AddressModel.PartialSelector)
```

where AddressModel.PartialSelector is an Expression itself.

By turning `p.Addresses` into an `IQueryable` using the `AsQueryable()` method, you allow the `Select()` method to use the version which takes in an Expression, instead of having to compile it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, he cannot.  That is not going to create an `Expression` object, and as such the query provider won't be able to inspect the code to translate it into a query.  Instead this will simply pull down the entire contents of the query into an in-memory object and then perform the transformation there.  It is important to *avoid* doing that.

Comment: This actually helped my particular situation where no other solution would, so it's not entirely without merit.